# How to select a value from a pop up screen to bring back to main screen in Excel VBA through Selenium?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I have a web form in which I enter repetitive data to configure the application. I am writing Excel VBA code to achieve this.

One field contains a pre-validated list of values, so there are two values SALES and SALES_TAX.
When I put SALES, it opens up a pop up screen. I want to select either through image or a radio button to bring the value back to the main screen.

Screenshot
[image]

A few commands that failed to achieve the desired result.

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='xo' and @id= 'N1:N8:0']").Click
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='N1:N8:0']").Click
driver.Actions.Click ("/SALES")pe here
```

---

One of my colleagues provided the following lines of code to resolve the issue.

```
e2 = "Sales, Sales and Use Tax"
e1 = "//td[(text() = '" & e2 & "')]" 
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
driver.FindElementByXPath(e1).Click
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This is not generic URL, it requires user id and password to go to the intended page.

Comment: One of my colleague helped with following lines of code to resolve the issue,
e2 = "Sales, Sales and Use Tax"
e1 = "//td[(text() = '" & e2 & "')]"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
driver.FindElementByXPath(e1).Click